# 2 GPUs with 6+8 pin connectors: does it help to use 4 cables instead of 2?

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply, cable

I am assembling a new pc and I reached the point where I need to connect the various power cables.

I have 2 graphic cards, each with 6 and 8 pin connectors. I understand I have to connect both for each graphic card.

The PSU is fully modular and comes with:

- 2 cables, each having 2 6+2 connectors
- 2 cables, each having a single 6+2 connector

Does it make a (noticeable) difference if I connect 1 cable per connector (i.e., all cables) vs 1 cable per card (i.e., only the first kind)?

If it makes a difference, the PSU is Corsair's AX760.

Comment: It doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Well there is cable management. One single wire vs 2... :)

Comment: @CarlB that's why I am asking the question: if there are significant benefits, I will deal with the extra cble management, otherwise I will happily avoid it :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing the internal structure of the PSU it's impossible to say for certain.

However, cable-management issues aside, the probability is that there is more than one output rail across those 4 cables, so using them all would give you a better chance of spreading the load across all possible rails
…which the PSU will thank you for, long-term.

*Update…*

From [Corsair](http://www.corsair.com/en-us/ax760-atx-power-supply-760-watt-80-plus-platinum-certified-fully-modular-psu)

> Features
>
> Dedicated single +12V rail

In which case, go with the fewest cables.

Comment: Is there a way to find out the internal structure of the PSU without voiding the garancy?

Comment: Corsair may provide a logical diagram somewhere. Most PSUs have 2 12v rails; some flag them on the casing so you know which is which, some don't. If you can't find out, then I'd say the downside of the additional cabling is well worth the upside of using both rails.

Comment: Updated answer - that PSU has a single rail, so reduce cable clutter rather than use them all.

Comment: I searched all yesterday and I couldn't find that info. It was under my nose! thanks.

Comment: Glad it helped :)